# Why this isn't working, it's giving me an this error ('bool' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is the code, it's a car parking system:

```
import time

parking_slots = []
start = []

for i in range(6):
    start.append(0)

for i in range(6):
    parking_slots.append(False)



while True:


    print("1.view empty\n2.add\n3.remove\n4.save\n5.load\n6.exit")

    choice = int(input())


    if choice == 1:
        print("Empty slots are: ")
        for slot in range(6):
            if parking_slots[slot] == 0:
                print(slot, end=" - ")
        print("")

    if choice == 2:
        index = int(input("Enter the index of the slot: "))
        if start[index] == 0:
            start[index] = int(time.time())
            parking_slots[index] = True
        else:
            print("this slot is already token, please choose another one")

    if choice == 3:
        index = int(input("Enter the index of the slot: "))
        print("Your bill is", int(time.time()) - start[index])
        parking_slots[index] = False
        start[index] = 0

    if choice == 4:
        open("cps.txt", "w").write("")
        for i in start:
            open("cps.txt", "a").write(str(i) + "\n")

    if choice == 5:
        file = open("cps.txt", "r").readlines()
        start = [float(x.strip("\n")) for x in file]
        for x in range(6):
            if start[x] == 0:
                parking_slots = False
            else:
                parking_slots = True

    if choice == 6:
        break
```

the error is when I enter choice 1, it tells me bool object is not subscriptable

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, I enter `1` and get a list of empty slots.

Answer (score 2):

When `choice == 5` you do

```
    for x in range(6):
        if start[x] == 0:
            parking_slots = False
        else:
            parking_slots = True
```

which replaces the list that was contained in `parking_slots` with a plain boolean, which gives you that error when you later try to index it. Probably here you meant

```
    for x in range(6):
        if start[x] == 0:
            parking_slots[x] = False
        else:
            parking_slots[x] = True
```